# How to fix MinGW filesystem probelem?

Tags: c++, c++17, clion

So I create a new C++17 Clion project, and include filesystem library.
When I try to run porject I have this error:

```
fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
```

I try to use: `#include <experimental/filesystem>`, with it namespace, but it doesn't work.

I use MinGW-w64 v. 6.0.

How Can I fix it?

Comment: Not CLion is the problem (it's the IDE only) but the compiler might be (or the standard library it is shipped with). Please, [edit] the question and add version info of compiler you are using in CLion.

Comment: your runtime library presumably doesn't support filesystem. Which one are you using? CLion is just an IDE

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: The compiler is looking for a specific file ('filesystem') in a subdirectory ('experimental') somewhere in its list of include directories. So to answer the question we need to know which compiler you are using (e.g. MingW / g++ / visual c++ / clang), and which version. It might be that the compiler does not support 'filesystem', or that it is installed incorrectly, or that the compiler is called in a wrong way. What command is executed by CLion to compile?

Comment: Get a newer compiler

Comment: All data from toolchains:

Environment: MinGW Version: w64 6.0

CMake: Bundled Version 3.15.3
Debugger: MinGW-w64 GDB Version: 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory

This message is issued by your compiler. The IDE merely relays the message to you.

To solve it, you must use a toolchain that supports C++17. In particular, you need a standard library that supports `<filesystem>`. This [issue track](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78870) suggests that it is implemented in trunk (but not enabled by default), and will be released in GCC version 9 (I don't know how that relates to MinGW version number).

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand - what I have to change for my project to work?

Comment: @tryToRunThisCommand Wait for a release of MinGW that supports `<filesystem>`, and upgrade to that release.

Answer (score 0):

I change toolchain from MinGw to Visual Studio and now all works fine.